# PHP echo with int values

Tags: php

To keep it short, why does

```
<?php
$var =  'Calc: ' . 5 - 5 . '!';
echo $var;
?>
```

output:

> -5!

Instead of, let's say:

> Calc: 0 . '!'

---

Or another variation of this problem:

```
<?php
echo "time is" . time()-2;
?>
```

Prints:

> -2

Notice the corruption, the first "string" with the first int is chopped off!
Though, <  $var =  'Calc: ' . (5 - 5) . '!';   > (does work ok), I'm trying to understand what the key concept behind this behavior is.

Comment: Welcome to the world of weakly typed languages. It is better to enforce typecasting.

Comment: Your question is why this happens and no how to fix it right?

Comment: @Dknacht - Right, I'm more concerned about why the first string + first int just get chopped off - that is unexpected behavior

Comment: the post has been marked as duplicate before i could submit my answer, so here you go : https://pastebin.com/U52aMi9X

Comment: Thank you @azjezz for your great answer, well detailed and explained.

Answer (score -2):

Good old math comes and saves the day.
Adding `()` means it will be calculated first and give you a correct string.

```
$var =  'Calc: ' . (5 - 5) . '!';
echo $var; //Calc: 0!
```

https://3v4l.org/p8OYf

Comment: The question is not how to solve it, he States at the end that he knows that using parentheses works ok. The question is why 5 - 5 gets inserted as -5 like the 5 was not there

Comment: @Dknacht and that is what my answer explains. The parentheses makes the code first evaluate the math. If it's not evaluated first then you will have a string that you try to do math on.